# Pandas shape mismatch. How to conditionally assign index to new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series `s`:

```
duration                           60
Name: 2017-10-14 02:05:31, dtype: object
```

and a dataframe `df`:

```
                     duration
Start Time
2017-10-14 02:00:00       300      
2017-10-14 02:05:00       100      
2017-10-14 02:10:00       250
```

I want to add `larger start time` column to `df` which stores whichever is larger: `s.name` OR `df.index`

My code:

```
   df.loc[df.index <= s.name, "larger start time"] = s.name
   df.loc[df.index > s.name, "larger start time"] = df.index #fails with shape mismatch
```

How can I modify my code to make this work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with

`df.loc[df.index > s.name, "larger start time"] = df.loc[df.index > s.name].index`